Components Refreshing on Mobile View
I have an issue with my React project that is only occurring on a mobile device where I'm noticing a lot of components seem to be refreshing?
Some examples are:

If im on the second page of a list of games and I open my nav bar by clicking the hamburger icon, it resets everything and goes to page 1.
If im just scrolling the home page, usually if i scroll a bit fast, then again the page resets and takes me to the top/resets to page 1

I've tried debugging and using memo and debounce but it continues to happen. I thought it may be to do with react-multi-carousel but even on a page where i don't use that it still happens and I'm unsure on how to even debug this further or what components you'd need to see to know why this is happening.
I'll stick with some core assets i.e.:
App.js:


import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import Routers from "./Routers/routers";
import { ViewportProvider } from "./hooks/ViewportProvider";
import background from "./assets/images/background.svg";
import "bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js";
import { checkTokenExpiryAndRefreshIfNeeded } from "./utils/auth";

export const Context = React.createContext();

function App() {
  const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState(false);
  const [activeCashOutPageTab, setActiveCashOutPageTab] = useState("withdrawal");

  useEffect(() => {
    

    const checkAuth = async () => {
      const token = await checkTokenExpiryAndRefreshIfNeeded();
      setIsLoggedIn(!!token);
    };

    checkAuth();
  }, []);

  return (
    <Context.Provider value={[isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn]}>
      <ViewportProvider>
        <div className="App" style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${background})` }}>
          <Routers
            activeCashOutPageTab={activeCashOutPageTab}
            setActiveCashOutPageTab={setActiveCashOutPageTab}
          />
        </div>
      </ViewportProvider>
    </Context.Provider>
  );
}

export default App;



Router.jsx:


import { React, useEffect } from "react";
import {
  Routes,
  Route,
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  useLocation,
} from "react-router-dom";
import Layout from "../layout/Layout";
import Home from "../pages/Home/home";
import Events from "../pages/Events/events";



// Category Images
import SlotBattlesImage from "../assets/images/CasinoCategories/slot_battles_button_bg.jpg";


function ScrollToTop() {
  const { pathname } = useLocation();
  useEffect(() => {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
  }, [pathname]);

  return null;
}

const Routers = ({ activeCashOutPageTab, setActiveCashOutPageTab }) => {
  const englishCategories = [
    { text: "Slot Battles", image: SlotBattlesImage },
  ];

  return (
    <Router>
      <ScrollToTop />
      <Routes>
        <Route
          path="/"
          element={
            <Layout>
              <Home categories={englishCategories} />
            </Layout>
          }
        />
        <Route
          path="/events"
          element={
            <Layout>
              <Events />
            </Layout>
          }
        />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
};

export default Routers;



I'd give the navbar.jsx but doubt its linked to one file because it happens even when scrolling?
My Layout.jsx is used as seen in the router but it doesn't look wrong? I've removed some code like parameters or basic functions to make it less of an eye-sore


import React, { useState, useEffect, useContext } from "react";
import Header from "./Header/header";
import NavBar from "./NavBar/navbar";
import Footer from "./Footer/footer";
import Content from "./Content/content";

import LoginPopup from "../components/LoginPopup/loginPopup";
import LogoutConfirmation from "../components/LogoutConfirmation/LogoutConfirmation";
import LocalizationSelectorPopup from "../components/LocalizationSelectorPopup/LocalizationSelectorPopup";

import i18n from "i18next";
import useAuth from "../hooks/useAuth"; // Make sure to import useAuth

const Layout = ({ children }) => {
  const [showLoginPopup, setShowLoginPopup] = useState(false);


  // Call useAuth to perform the authentication check
  useAuth();

  useEffect(() => {
    const storedLanguage = localStorage.getItem("selectedLanguage");
    if (storedLanguage) {
      setSelectedLanguage(storedLanguage);
      i18n.changeLanguage(storedLanguage);
    }
  }, []);
  

  const handleLanguageChange = (language) => {
    setSelectedLanguage(language);
    localStorage.setItem("selectedLanguage", language);
    i18n.changeLanguage(language);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {showLoginPopup && (
        <LoginPopup/>
      )}
      {showLocalizationPopup && (
        <LocalizationSelectorPopup
          setShowLocalizationPopup={setShowLocalizationPopup}
          setSelectedLanguage={handleLanguageChange}
          selectedLanguage={selectedLanguage}
        />
      )}
      {showLogoutConfirmation && (
        <LogoutConfirmation/>
      )}
      <Header
        isLoggedIn={isLoggedIn}
        handleSignInClick={handleSignInClick}
        handleLogout={handleLogout}
      />
      <NavBar
        isLoggedIn={isLoggedIn}
        handleSignInClick={handleSignInClick}
        handleLogout={handleLogout}
        hamburgerOpen={hamburgerOpen}
        setHamburgerOpen={setHamburgerOpen}
        setShowLocalizationPopup={setShowLocalizationPopup}
        selectedLanguage={selectedLanguage}
      />
      <Content selectedLanguage={selectedLanguage}>{children}</Content>
      <Footer />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Layout;



Index.js


import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import './i18n';
import { RecentlyPlayedProvider } from './context/RecentlyPlayedContext';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <RecentlyPlayedProvider>
      <App />
    </RecentlyPlayedProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);

reportWebVitals();



I'm not sure what else is needed to make this easier for someone to give some pointers or where to look? If you require any more info please let me know. Thanks
I added Console.log to layout, and i notice that the console.log is printing everytime i even do a little action i.e. click nav bar..?
UPDATE
If i dont use layout around the router route and take out the nav bar and manually insert it into my page jsx - it solves the issue so i wonder why the layout is causing issues

Is it happening on a single mobile device or all the mobile devices ? and Can you be able to share the in which browser you are loading app and what is the operating system ? By saying components are getting refreshed you mean just a react re-render happening or complete tab is reloading ?

Happening on all mobile devices. I have tried on both Safari and Chrome. I have tried on iOS and Android. And by reloading i mean the components are re-rendering. Doesn't seem to affect desktop.

I've noticed that my Layout.jsx - i added a console.log("layout  rendered") in const Layout = ({ children }) => { } and thats occurring 2 times when i click anything. I dont think it should re-render every time right?

console.log("layout rendered") appearing twice might be a side effect of React Strict mode if you are running in development mode. In strict mode any state updates will be triggered twice and cause couple of re-renders.
